# Ordenar objeto de meses y años

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo el siguiente array con datos que me llegan por una petición a mi base:

```
{
"Agosto/2021": 1918017.7399999998,
"Mayo/2021": 1134546.27,
"Octubre/2021": 2166282.3,
"Diciembre/2021": 2237852.71,
"Noviembre/2021": 2180166.5399999996,
"Junio/2021": 1423141.42,
"Julio/2021": 1829257.4100000001,
"Septiembre/2021": 1944794.68,
"Marzo/2021": 1784555.2,
"Abril/2021": 1291571.06,
"Febrero/2022": 1911418.6600000001,
"Enero/2022": 2409753.9199999995}
```

Lo que quiero es ordenarlo por mes y año, en este caso sería Marzo/2021, Abril/2021 etc etc y al último Enero/2022 y Febrero/2022.

Conseguí ordenarlo pero sacando las keys y aplicando la siguiente función con momentjs

```
Object.keys(group).sort((a, b) => a.split('/')[1] - b.split('/')[1] || moment().month(a.split('/')[0]).format('MM') - moment().month(b.split('/')[0]).format('MM')).map(mes => mes)
```

Pero esto solo me saca las keys y me ordena las keys, yo necesito con keys y valores ordenados al mes correspondiente

Comment: Si ya tienes las claves ordenadas puedes iterarlas y construir un nuevo objeto que incluya los valores.

Comment: Hola. De que forma lo harías?

Comment: Si, si ya tiene las keys ordenadas, puede hacerse un array donde inserte la key y el valor en orden desde el objeto `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tu caso**

En principio un objeto en javascript no tiene un orden como podrías plantearlo en otros lenguajes, pero puedes "engañar" al intérprete construyéndolo de nuevo siguiendo el orden que has establecido. Funcionará para tu caso pero de rebote. Después de este snippet trataré de explicarlo:

```js
const group = {
"Agosto/2021": 1918017.7399999998,
"Mayo/2021": 1134546.27,
"Octubre/2021": 2166282.3,
"Diciembre/2021": 2237852.71,
"Noviembre/2021": 2180166.5399999996,
"Junio/2021": 1423141.42,
"Julio/2021": 1829257.4100000001,
"Septiembre/2021": 1944794.68,
"Marzo/2021": 1784555.2,
"Abril/2021": 1291571.06,
"Febrero/2022": 1911418.6600000001,
"Enero/2022": 2409753.9199999995
}

const meses = Object.keys(group).sort((a, b) => a.split('/')[1] - b.split('/')[1] || moment().month(a.split('/')[0]).format('MM') - moment().month(b.split('/')[0]).format('MM')).map(mes => mes)

const new_group = {}
for(i in meses){
  new_group[meses[i]] = group[meses[i]];
}
console.log(new_group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/es.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Cosas raras pero no tan raras**

Hagamos ahora una prueba. Vamos a insertar entre Enero/2022 y Febrero/2022 un nuevo registro cuya key sea "2022"

```js
const group = {
"Agosto/2021": 1918017.7399999998,
"Mayo/2021": 1134546.27,
"Octubre/2021": 2166282.3,
"Diciembre/2021": 2237852.71,
"Noviembre/2021": 2180166.5399999996,
"Junio/2021": 1423141.42,
"Julio/2021": 1829257.4100000001,
"Septiembre/2021": 1944794.68,
"Marzo/2021": 1784555.2,
"Abril/2021": 1291571.06,
"Febrero/2022": 1911418.6600000001,
"Enero/2022": 2409753.9199999995
}

const meses = Object.keys(group).sort((a, b) => a.split('/')[1] - b.split('/')[1] || moment().month(a.split('/')[0]).format('MM') - moment().month(b.split('/')[0]).format('MM')).map(mes => mes)

const new_group = {}
for(i in meses){
  new_group[meses[i]] = group[meses[i]];
  if(meses[i] == 'Enero/2022'){
    new_group['2022'] = 'Por qué aparezco aquí?';
  }
}
console.log(new_group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/es.min.js"></script>
```

Si ejecutas el código verás que el resultado es el siguiente:

```javascript
{
  "2022": "Por qué aparezco aquí?",
  "Marzo/2021": 1784555.2,
  "Abril/2021": 1291571.06,
  "Mayo/2021": 1134546.27,
  "Junio/2021": 1423141.42,
  "Julio/2021": 1829257.4100000001,
  "Agosto/2021": 1918017.7399999998,
  "Septiembre/2021": 1944794.68,
  "Octubre/2021": 2166282.3,
  "Noviembre/2021": 2180166.5399999996,
  "Diciembre/2021": 2237852.71,
  "Enero/2022": 2409753.9199999995,
  "Febrero/2022": 1911418.6600000001
}
```

Esto ocurre porque en javascript el orden de las propiedades del objeto se establece por las siguientes reglas:

- Primero números de manera ascendente
- Después caracteres en el orden que fueron añadidos
- Para terminar, los símbolos según fueron añadidos

---

**Consejo**

La pregunta que deberías hacerte es si necesitas realmente ordenar las propiedades del objeto. Podrías tener una estructura más sencilla con un array de objetos.

No tendría fe ciega en soluciones de este tipo porque realmente la estructura que necesitas para el tipo de datos no debería ser un objeto.